# ERROR selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException (he browser pop-up window does not close)

Tags: python

I can't close the pop-up window,I wrote a function that in fact should close the window, well, it does not close, and even more so even the exception does not work immediately throws the same error
I will be grateful for your help, I have already spent a large amount of time in different ways, it does not help, and I tried to find it through xpatch and through the class

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])


def start(message):  
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Создаеться прайс")
    b = 0

    # Эльдорадо
    #while True:
    link_eldo = "https://www.mvideo.ru/product-list-page-cls?q=redmi&limit=12&region_id=1&category_id=cat2_cis_0000000357" 
    print (requests.get(link_eldo))
    # requests_url = requests.get(link_eldo)
    # if requests_url.status_code == 403:
    #   print("Получилось")
    #    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent.random}")
       
    driver.get(link_eldo)
    
    def func (i):
        i = i + 1
        return i
    def close_banner(browser):
      wait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "close"))).click()
      

    #time.sleep(20)
    name_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div['func(0)']/div[3]/div/div[1]/h4/a")
    price_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fl-product-tile-price__current")

    name_product = []
    price_product = []
    
    for name in name_eldo_product:
      name_product.append(name.text)
    for price in price_eldo_product:
      price = price.text
      price = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', price)
      rub = "р"
      for clear in rub:
        price = price.replace(clear,"")
      price_product.append(int(price))
      print(price_product)

    сreat_dic = dict(zip(name_product, price_product))

    main_products = {}
  
    main_products.update(сreat_dic)

    print (main_products)



    link_eldo = "https://www.mvideo.ru/product-list-page-cls?q=iphone12&limit=12&region_id=1&category_id=cat2_cis_0000000357" 
    print (requests.get(link_eldo))
    # requests_url = requests.get(link_eldo)
    # if requests_url.status_code == 403:
    #   print("Получилось")
    #    options.add_argument(f"user-agent={user_agent.random}")
       
    driver.get(link_eldo)
    
    
    

   
    
    try:
       close_banner(driver)
       name_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div['func(0)']/div[3]/div/div[1]/h4/a")
       price_eldo_product = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("fl-product-tile-price__current")
       
       
    except NoSuchElementException:
        #spelling error making this code not work as expected
      pass
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
      close_banner(driver)
      
      pass
    except TimeoutException:
        print('poput')
```